After Effects replace 3d layers in existing comp from new comp
i'm using the "run script" function in After Effects to run a .jsx, it creates a new comp that contains keyframed cameras and Nulls as 3D Objects. These Cameras and Nulls come from Blender.
In my workflow i parent 3D Text, or other layers to those Nulls, now after i've changed a few positions and animations in Blender i export another jsx. After running that one again in AE it will create a new composition containing the adjusted or newly added cameras and nulls. I now want to copy these over to my old "Master" Composition, since i've got everything set up there. How can i copy and replace those new layers over, keeping my parenting, masking relationships, without creating duplicates?
Thanks in advance.
I thought about creating a script, but my understanding is far too limited in that regard.
